# Strange Camera Shadow

Tags: rendering, procedural

So, I think I have narrowed down an issue I'm having with a procedural texture. When rendering and my camera is close to the model I get a magenta shadow from the camera, it follows the camera, and playing with the texture I can minimize or exaggerate it but can't get rid of it. This is mid render where it is the MOST prevalent but you can clearly see the magenta. Would love some help so I can start rendering this, thank you for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what the camera has to do with the textures in the material, but since you didn't upload an image where the settings are very legible, I couldn't bother to investigate by guessing your settings. Apart from that, most likely it is not the shader setup alone, but the interaction of shader, object, camera. So without knowing the camera settings and the scene's objects it would be all just speculation. Probably it would be best to upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question. MAybe check if camera, ground object an material are enough to show the issue.

Comment: Please do split out the minimal.blend that displays the problem, and share as suggested.. otherwise this question is vulnerable to being voted 'unclear'